# Add role in spring with custom userDetailsService using okta authentication

Tags: java, spring, okta

I followed this great tuto : https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/06/crud-angular-9-spring-boot-2#spring-boot-as-an-oauth-2-0-resource-server

I would like to add Roles to the spring part. I don’t want to use claims like in this tuto https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/26/build-a-spring-boot-webapp but I would like to add my customs role (from my own db).

I tryed to override userDetailsService() from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to use my custom UserDetailService. But it seems this method is never called … (see println), should it be?

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        //@formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            System.out.println("yo");
            Optional<co.simplon.blog.model.User> user = userRepository.findByName(username);

            return User
                    .withUsername(username)
                    .password(user.get().getPassword())
                    .authorities(Arrays.asList(user.get().getRole()))
                    .accountExpired(false)
                    .accountLocked(false)
                    .credentialsExpired(false)
                    .disabled(false)
                    .build();
        };
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi @Josselin Could you figure out this issue. I have the same requirement. But couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Hi @biky, I didn't figure out this issue. It was ok for me to use jwt (spring) + firebase (angular).

Answer (score 0):

you have to add you UserDetailsService implementation in the WebConfigurerSEcurityAdapter:

```
    @Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)
        throws Exception {
    builder.userDetailsService(new MyUserDetailsService());
}
```

Then you'll see that your implementation will start being called.